# Angular append id to put/delete request

Tags: angular, typescript, http-method

currently I am trying to append an Id number to each of my http(such as http://202.160.1.102:8084/api/aq/{id}) for my put/delete request. The put method i am trying to submit is onClickUpdate(), I am using a Ngfor to loop through all my results in the edit.component.html and they are all in formgroup but below is my edit.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import  { AQ } from '../AQ';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit2',
  templateUrl: './edit2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit2.component.css']
})
export class Edit2Component implements OnInit {

  todayForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  data_aq: AQ[]
  public formID = this.todayForm.controls['ID'].value

  constructor(
    private HttpClient: HttpClient,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  } {
    this.todayForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ID: [''],
      District: [''],
      Value: [''],
      LastUpdate: [''],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.HttpClient.get('http://202.160.1.102:8084/api/aq').subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.data_aq = < AQ[] > data
      })

    this.todayForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ID: [''],
      District: [''],
      Value: [''],
      LastUpdate: [''],
    });
    let formID = this.todayForm.controls['ID'].value
  }

  onClickUpdate(formID) {
    this.HttpClient.put('http://202.160.1.102:8084/api/aq/' + formID, this.todayForm.value).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.todayForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    alert('SUCCESS!! :-)');
  }

}
```

My issue is now that i keep on getting an error request when i send a put request via client.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

I would also want to know would delete method for Angular is just to add the delete method on the httpclient? such that the method to delete would be:

```
onClickDelete(formID) {
  this.HttpClient.put('http://202.160.1.102:8084/api/aq/' + formID, this.todayForm.value).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  });
  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.todayForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  alert('SUCCESS!! :-)')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the `get` API on the FormGroup instead of directly accessing the controls like this. Change

```
let formID = this.todayForm.controls['ID'].value
```

to

```
let formID = this.todayForm.get('ID').value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Lamda Expression Function like

```
onClickDelete = (formID) => {
   this.HttpClient.put('http://202.160.1.102:8084/api/aq/' + formID ,this.todayForm.value).subscribe(data=>{
          console.log(data)
       })
        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.todayForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        alert('SUCCESS!! :-)')



    }
}
```

And For Delete Method Use

```
this.httpclient.delete('http://202.160.1.102:8084/api/aq/' + this.todayForm.value).subscribe(data => {
console.log(data)
```

});